# Find the volume inside the curve $x^2+4z^2+8y=16$ and on the positive side of $xz$-plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

Find the volume inside the curve $x^2+4z^2+8y=16$ and on the positive side of $xz$-plane.

What will be the volume of this as I'm getting wrong answer?

As per me the volume is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqWyq.png).

Please help me as I'm unable to get it.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Since you think you have got the wrong answer, if you post your solution, we can show you where you made a mistake.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yes this answers the question but if you could guide me from where that 4 comes from in the integral? I'm confused on that!

Comment: Sorry... when you duplicate a question you should delete yours and focus on the original question that has already been asked and answered.

Comment: @player3236 below is the attached image of my solution, and I've also mentioned the integral pls check once.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork sir i've not duplicated the question i was going through a booklet where i came across this question and solved it but my answer was wrong i got  $$\ 2pi $$ so i posted it here & when you mentioned the above link, it made my answer correct i.e $$\ 8pi $$ but i had the confusion that where that 4 came from....so I asked it....below is my solution also you can check...and sorry if you felt that i have duplicated the question.

Answer (score 0):

@player3236
my answer is in the image, please let me know where i went wrong, Thank you in advance
$$v = \int_0^2 \int_0^\sqrt{16-4z^2} 1/8(16-x^2 +4z^2) \,dx\,dz$$

---

$$v = \int_0^2 \int_0^\sqrt{16-4z^2} (2-x^2/8 +z^2/2) \,dx\,dz$$

[My solution for the above question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKcgO.jpg)

Comment: Fortunately your calculations for the integrals are all correct. The only mistake is the $1/8$ in front. Why do you think it is $1/8$?

Comment: because as mentioned in the question for xz-plane and the equation of paraboloid given is  $x^2+4z^2+8y=16$ so that is why 1/8 but answer is $$/ 8pi $$

Comment: But $\int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt \cdots}$ is only in one octant. There are four octants above the $xz$-plane.

Comment: @player3236 you are correct but there are 2 positive octant of xz plane!

Comment: Positive side of $xz$-plane $\iff y>0$

Comment: thank you @player3236

Answer (score 0):

Correct integral - $$v = 4\int_0^2 \int_0^\sqrt{16-4z^2} 1/8(16-x^2 +4z^2) \,dx\,dz$$

Correct Answer is $$ {8pi} $$

below is the correct solution of the given question -
[image: Correct Solution]